# Corresponding value of kSecAttrAccessControl?

Tags: ios, swift2, keychain

What is the type of the corresponding value of kSecAttrAccessControl? From the docs, it says that the value will be the return value of [SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(_:_:_:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags) and can be used in creating a query for SecItemAdd, etc.

However, in Swift 2, this does not seem to work. I get errSecParam error when I try to add an item. It is understood that in Swift 1, you can use .takeRetainedValu() to solve this. But, that doesn't seem to be the case in Swift 2.

Here is the Psuedo code:

```
    func addItem() -> String {

    // Build a query for adding a keychain item.
    let account: String! = "testAccount"
    let service: String! = "testService"
    let accessible: String! = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked as String
    let data: NSData! = "test data".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let acl: SecAccessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked, .UserPresence, nil)!

    let query = [
        kSecClass as String         :   kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
        kSecAttrAccount as String   :   account,
        kSecAttrService as String   :   service,
        kSecAttrAccessible as String:   accessible,
        kSecAttrAccessControl as String :   acl, //errSecParam because of acl!
        kSecValueData as String     :   data
    ] as NSDictionary

    status = SecItemAdd(query, nil)

    if status != errSecSuccess {
        print("[addItem::SecItemAdd] \(osstatusToHumanReadable(status))")
    }

    return osstatusToHumanReadable(status)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be your problem. Both **kSecAttrAccessible** and **kSecAttrAccessControl** seem to be mutually exclusive, meaning that both cannot coexist.

Try to remove one and use the other (your choice, as my knowledge of both is not enough to give advice).

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/ksecattraccesscontrol)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @kaspar for getting back on this. You are correct, I figured it out shortly after after I posted here and went onto finish my project. Here, is the link in case you are interested: [https://github.com/NitinJami/keychaineditor](https://github.com/NitinJami/keychaineditor).

Comment: Your answer might be correct, but your reasoning is not. The documentation only says that `kSeAttrAccessControl` and `kSecAttrAccess` are mutually exclusive. But `kSecAttrAccess` is not the same as `kSecAttrAccessible`.